# Do *ALL* mobile/touch browsers have “invisible” scrollbars in scrollable areas?

Tags: mobile, touch-screen, browser, scrollbars

Usually in browsers in touch devices, in scrollable areas, a scrollbar only appears when a user touches it and starts scrolling by moving their finger (in some it never appears at all).

Is this something I can count on 100% to be implemented in ALL mobile/touch browsers? (i.e. none will show an always-visible scrollbar by default) 
I need to know, for a design decision.

Comment: You can't design for *all* browsers and devices in existence. But what you *can* do is identify the main browsers in use in your target market and design the experience to be optimal for those devices and ensure that the app  / site still functions (i.e. is still usable) on other niche devices. It might not look 1:1 the same on these devices but provided the functionality is still there then you can concentrate your design decisions on the large majority of browsers that are in use.

Answer (score 3):

No. You can never expect a particular feature to be implemented the same way across all varieties and vendors of a type of software.

Heck. Often companies and platforms even have internal differences; try doing a google search for all the types of sliders in Photoshop, Illustrator etcetera.

And regarding this particular instance, a 1 minute search in the Google Play store resulted in the "old but gold" browser:

[image]

Comment: Can you please elaborate on old but gold bit? Are you saying IE is available on Playstore?

Comment: No, I'm saying there is a browser on the playstore literally called "old but gold". I presume it uses chromium for rendering etc and is just a skin for nostalgic feelings. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.maskyn.oldbrowser

Comment: BTW, I looked into this browser. Interestingly, its user-agent string contains "MSIE6" (read: "Microsoft Internet Explorer 6"), of-course it doesn't necessarily mean anything, but it sure feels like it's using IE6 engine :) Also, from what I saw, I'm pretty sure that giant "scrollbar" there on the side is a meaningless visual element just "for show", because I haven't seen a page there where it actually controls the scrolling. This doesn't invalidate your answer though. Finally, I found out I'm able to detect the width of a scrollbar in a pretty crossbrowser way, so I can use two designs,

Comment: @YuvalA. The user agent string simply tells the server what version to show. Some websites have different styles for different browsers (most commonly, a barebones version for web crawlers/spiters). It doesn't necesarilly say anything about the render engine, and given that Internet Explorer is proprietary software, I highly doubt this particular browser is using the Trident rendering engine.